# Access stored procedure not working

Tags: ms-access, vba

The following stored procedure is not working, I have tried everything without success. Help please.

```
Sub Create_View()

    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection

    Set conn = Application.CurrentProject.Connection

    conn.Execute "CREATE VIEW vw_RobPS AS " & _
    "SELECT sid, " & _
    "Lname, " & _
    "Fname, " & _
    "EmpStatus, " & _
    "[Peax Update as of 6-18-15], " & _
    "[Peax Update Date] " & _
    "FROM Master_06-18-2015" & _
    "WHERE [Peax Update Date] as PeaxUdDt is not null; "

    Application.RefreshDatabaseWindow

ExitHere:
  If Not conn Is Nothing Then
    If conn.State = adStateOpen Then conn.Close
  End If

    Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

When, I run it, I get this error message:

> Run-time error'-2147217900(80040e14)': Syntax error in FROM clause.

I can't find the problem.

Comment: Since `conn` refers to `CurrentProject.Connection`, I don't understand why you want to do `conn.Close`.   Does that actually work?

Answer (score 6):

1. Your table name includes dashes;  enclose that name in square brackets
2. Include a space between the table name and `WHERE`
3. Don't try to alias a field in the `WHERE` clause

```sql
"FROM [Master_06-18-2015] " & _
"WHERE [Peax Update Date] is not null; "
```